# How to get the mouse position from 'drag' events in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

With "draggable" domNoes, the 'drag' event doesn't seem to contain any mouse information at all (like offsetX and offsetY) like it does in chrome. How can I get this information while dragging?

I've tried setting a 'mousemove' event handler on the document, but it seems like that isn't fired when something is being dragged. Same seems to be true in chrome. What a drag..

I'm using Firefox 30.

Answer (score 4):

`drag` events are used on the elements that are being dragged. `dragover` can be used on other elements that stay stationary such that something is dragged over them. If you ask for `clientX` or `clientY` on `drag` events, you will get zeros. If you drag that element over an element with `dragover`, and ask *that* event for coordinates, you will get x and y relative to the `dragover` listening element.

Easiest example to see it in action is to apply `dragover` to the document object, then drag something over it and print the x and y.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Sorry for the delayed response, I've been very busy. If you have the mousemove event attached to the actual document rather than the element, then it should still fire. For example:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler, true);
```

Notice that I set the boolean at the end to "true"; this means that the event fires in the capture phase. It should update the coordinates in your mouse move function as you're needing. As for getting the element being dragged, you can get that element reference from event.target in the drag handler, like this:

```
function dragHandler(e) {
    var el = e.target; //this is the element being dragged
}
```

You can use this to ascertain the offset of the element that you're dragging:

```
var rectObject = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var top_offset = rectObject.top;
var left_offset = rectObject.left;
```

If you need mouse coordinates, you'll need to attach a mousemove event listener to the DOM and store the coordinates in a global variable so that you can access them in the drag listener.

Comment: And how do you get the element being dragged? As I understand 'draggable', the element in question itself isn't moved at all unless you affect it inside the drag event handlers. Also, as I metioned in the question, mousemove doesn't get fired while dragging something.

Comment: For me, adding "true" to useCapture did not make the event fire while dragging in either Chrome or FF =/